# Effect of adding a Pole and Zero due to PID

Tags: control-theory

I am kinda confused on how Adding a D(which adds a zero to the complete system) decreases the speed of the system. But when we normally add a zero to the system, it normally causes the system overshoot.

The same goes for the I part of the PID. Normally when we add an pole to the system, we the system would usually become less overshoot, but the I part increases the overshoot??...

What i mean the addition of an Integration and the derivative can be described when we look at at PI or a PD controller. 
the integrater is $K_i/s$ which adds a pole to the complete transfer function. 
And the D part is $K_dS$ adds a zero to the complete transfer function.

How does the inverse relation make sense??

This how i understand it:

Adding a pole lead to less overshoot, since adding a pole, adds a decaying part for the transfer function in time domain.  $e^{-(1/a)t}$

Adding a zero, depending on the placement of zero either leads  high overshoot or less overshoot.   If the Zero is placed before the complex conjugated poles, it will lead to overshoot, and if is placed after it leads to less overshoot.

Comment: So I have found [this page](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/econtrolhtml/pid/pid3.html) and [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#PID_Pole_Zero_Cancellation), but perhaps it would be helpful to know what you mean by "adding a zero" or "adding a pole"?  Are you talking about how the integral part can help stabilize a PID system?

Comment: Part of the "inverse relation" is the fact that the D (derivative) is added into the system by $sD$ but the I (integral) part is added by $\dfrac Is$.  The integral part is the source of the pole (as you observe, the pole is at $s=0$) and the derivative part is the source of an "extra" zero, in the sense that $P+\dfrac Is$ is "linear" as $\dfrac {Ps+I}s$ and $P+\dfrac Is+sD$ is quadratic as $\dfrac {Ps+I+s^2D}s$...

Comment: So, when you say "normally when we add a zero to the system..." what is "normal" in comparison with this question?

Comment: for the PID controller it is possible to simplify the transfer function so no extra zero or poles will be added, but for PI or PD they should have an overall effect on the system.

Comment: To stabilize a system

Comment: Note that taking the "before phase" or "after phase" model of the integral and derivative parts of the PID suggests that both parts can either cause overshoot or stabilize the system, depending on the constants used.

Comment: I am working on a better response to this, but it will take me some time.

Comment: May it be incorrect to look at the system as one whole.. I mean Imagine that the closed transfer function with an PID would look like this 
$T(S) = \frac{\frac{kp}{s(s+1)}\frac{ki}{s(s(s+1))} + \frac{kd*s}{s(s+1)}}{1+ \frac{kp}{s(s+1)}\frac{ki}{s(s(s+1))} + \frac{kd*s}{s(s+1)}}$

Comment: If that were the case, you essentially have $\dfrac x{1+x}=1-\dfrac 1{1+x}$.  That seems like a pretty straightforward PI transfer function to me...  Also, do you mean to have two pluses on the top and three on the bottom for the major terms, or is the first pair of terms multiplied?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14525/discussion-between-control-and-abiessu)